# set up aurelia with vs 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core, aurelia

I have [followed the instructions](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/2) on installing aurelia to work with visual studio

Namely that you should:

> open a command line and change directory into your web project's project folder. This is the folder that contains the .xproj file. From within this folder, you can execute the following command au new --here which will setup Aurelia "here" inside this project folder. You will be prompted to choose the platform you want. Simply select "ASP.NET Core".

I have done the above and ended up with this:

[image]

I dont understand how this is supposed to work (and it doesnt work)

The `index.html` is the only file thats located within wwwroot and when you issue a `au build` the components are built into the `scripts` folder that lies *outside* wwwroot.

What is the recommended way to get this to work? Are you supposed to instruct the au cli to build into wwwroot?

Also `au run` (which also doesnt work as it cant find index.html) is not the preferred way to develop the app as it runs its own webserver and i want the aurelia app to talk to the web api backend that is running via visual studio.

As a bonus it would be nice if somehow Visual Studio could automatically issue an `au build` when something changes in the UI so you dont have to go to the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found VS2015 relatively sluggish when you run node based apps from inside wwwroot.

Of course you can hide some of the folders
[How can I hide files from Solution Explorer by name in VS2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175235/how-can-i-hide-files-from-solution-explorer-by-name-in-vs2015/33837657#33837657) but still I found VS constantly locking and slowing down when I change the node folder (e.g. when you install a package via npm).

So here is my setup:

1. Create your VS2015 Asp.Net Core project `.\SolutionFolder\WebApplication`
2. Create a separate folder outside of the Asp.Net Core `.\SolutionFolder\WebUi`
3. Run the `au new` and I always go with options:

   - Default Setup: `3 - Custom`
   - Transpiler: `2 - Typescript`
   - Templates: `3 - Maximum Minification` (not that it's relevant during development)
   - CSS Processor: `2 - Less` - feel free to chose your own processor, I just like less
   - Default Code Editor: `1 - Visual Studio Code` https://code.visualstudio.com/
4. Then in `Startup.cs` in my project I tell my app to load the custom folder:

   ```
   #if DEBUG
   app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
   {
       FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"FullPath\SolutionFolder\WebUi"),
       RequestPath = new PathString("/app")
   });
   #endif
   ```
5. Make sure when you deploy that you deploy your aurelia app in the `./app` folder or alternatively you can try do deploy in root.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: for anyone else who stumbles upon this i went with a slightly modified solution that uses visual studio 2015 for both the back and front end.
The stroke of wisdom is as you indicate to have a separate folder for the aurelia project `WebUi` and then this can be added to a visual studio by right clicking the solution and `Add -> Existing Web Site...` - you can if you wish hide the `node_modules` folder using windows explorer. Lastly instead of using `app.UseFileServer` i used `builder.UseWebRoot(fullPathToUiFolder)` which means your asp.net core app will serve the aurelia app